# How can send I session data in the Blueimp jquery file uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, blueimp

I'm trying to use codeigniter and the Blueimp Jquery File Upload plugin for the project I'm currently working on: Filtering images for display based on an authenticated user. I need to be able to change the path of the uploads, based on a GET variable on the page that contains the plugin. I want it to connect to a separate folder for each user.

To do this I believe I need to accomplish only one more step: make the codeigniter session ID, which i have in a hidden field in the form available to a server side script in cases where the $_request, $_POST, or $_GET arrays are **not** set.

from googling around it appears that [Jquery File Upload plugin: Dynamically change upload path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056171/jquery-file-upload-plugin-dynamically-change-upload-path) is exactly what I am trying to do.

The only problem is that the last step is not explained! I am brand new to JS, Jquery and ajax. Could someone explain how to use jquery to make the session ID available in a php script.

as a hint the blueimp author wrote the following in https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/241

> Have a look at example/application.js, the second section is commented with
>   // Load existing files:
>   There, add
>   + '?ext=VAR1&nota=VAR2'
>   behind
>   $('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX('option', 'url')
>   and adjust VAR1 and VAR2 to your desired path variables.

The code in the current main.js file is

```
$('#fileupload').each(function () {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON(this.action, function (result) {
            if (result && result.length) {
                $(that).fileupload('option', 'done')
                    .call(that, null, {result: result});
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Are you sure you need the session id to be put in as part of the query string? Your session id should be sent down as a cookie to the user and then automatically back up with the upload. If you need something special you can set it before you display the page the first time in $_SESSION. It should be available there again when you're trying the parse the file. At that point you can move it where you need it, rather than making it go to a different folder in the upload javascript. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi mcarpenter, thanks for your comments. Just for my understanding , if I were to store the session ID in a cookie would it be available to both server and client sides? As far as I can tell the author suggested handling it by tacking the session ID onto the a query string in jquery ( please see above code )

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be required to be passed separately, and your session id should already be a cookie unless codeigniter does something funky with its sessions. I use the blueimp code myself and I don't worry about sending any extra session info. I'll post my example of how I do it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a chunk of code I use to run the blueimp upload and is running on a production site. As you can see, I don't care about appending any session data on at all. I simply tell it the url to upload to and then some callback methods to be called as it does its work. The one caveat I'll add here is that I am using only the basic plugin which I am styling myself.

```
$("#file").fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/Upload/Photo"
        start: function () {
            progress.show();
        },
        progress: function (e, data) {
            progress.progressbar({ value: (data.loaded / data.total) * 100 });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            progress.hide();
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            progress.hide();
            var message = "An error was encountered!";

            // Use the simplemodal plugin to show my error
            modal.showError(message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi mcarpenter. I finally got it working using your original idea of using the codeigniter session cookie. Part of the problem is that the blueimp plugin is not 'inside' codeigniter in my setup and so standard codeigniter functions do not work in this context. After realizing this I was able to substitute generic php and get it working. Thank you for your help and your jquery examples. I now have a minimal understanding of Ajax. Regards - Bill