# How to set the upload destination dynamically via jQuery (blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload )

Tags: php, jquery, upload, blueimp

This is a question regarding blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload, which can be found here:

[blueimp's jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Does anyone know how to set the upload destination url or folder via jQuery? Using the downloaded example for PHP, could you provide an example?

Thanks very much!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11056171/114029

Answer (score -1):

The Blueimp gallery plugin has a .js file named main.js just change this line:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
});
```

for your previusly declared, DynamicVar:

```
var DynamicVar = "MyDynamic/folder";

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: DynamicVar
});
```

Cheers!.

Comment: Stumbled upon this, I don't think the URL defines the destination folder. It should point to the handler code, for example the `UploadHandler.php` that ships with Blueimp.